# Why is DataFrame Empty in Pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am fairly new to Python and trying to figure out why this code is producing an empty dataframe.

The code within the quotation marks is SQL. It is running that query in a particular database. When I paste a similar query for another database, the code works fine. Any suggestions as to what might be going wrong?

```
query_uk = """
Select distinct date,id from (
(Select * from uktable
where date between %s and %s + interval 1 day )
UNION
(Select * from uktable2
where date between %s and %s + interval 1 day ) )a
"""

query_us = """
Select distinct date,id
from ustable
where date between %s and %s + interval 1 day
"""

def get_data(country,date):
    if country == 'uk':
        df1 = query_to_df(query_uk%(date,date,date,date))
        return df1
    if country == 'us':
        df2 = query_to_df(query_us%(date,date))
        return df2
```

The code produces the following result:

Empty DataFrame

Columns: [txnDate, id]

Index: []

I was expecting it to generate a long table of dates and ids. If I paste these queries into SQL, this seems to work.

Edit: Sorry, it was meant to be date, not date_start

Comment: I didnt see where you declared "date_start,date_start,date_start,date_start" in the get_data. That will mean the query wont return anything. Do you mean 'date' instead?

Comment: Aside from your question, you should escape your sql parameters in order to avoid a SQL Injection Attack., In `pyodbc` for example, your params should be written as `?` on the query, and then pass in the parameters in the `params` argument of `pd.read_sql_query`

Answer (score 0):

made your query call like below

```
 pd.read_sql_query(
        sql=('Select distinct date,id from ustable where date between %s and %s + interval 1 day' % date_start,%date_end),
        db_connection_string)
```